# Cannot login to wordpress with curl and php

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, curl

I am trying to make a function in php using curl, that logs into my local wordpress, but I am getting into trouble.

I have this function:

```
function wordpressLogin($username, $password, $loginUrl, $visitUrl, $userAgent, $cookieFile) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init') || !function_exists('curl_exec')) {
        echo 'curl is not available!';
    }

    //$postData = "log=". $login_user ."&pwd=" . $login_pass . "&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=" . $visit_url;
    $postData = "log=$username&pwd=$password&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=$visitUrl&testcookie=1";

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Url to use for login
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

    //Activate cookiejar
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

    //Set cookie
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile );

    //No need for SSL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);

    //Timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    //Follow redirection
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    //Return or echo
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //Referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginUrl);

    //POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


    //Save result to content
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    //Close curl
    curl_close($ch);

    //Return content
    echo $content;
}

//Testing

$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';

$loginUrl = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php';
$visitUrl = urlencode('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin');
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0';
$cookieFile = '/tmp/cookie.txt';

wordpressLogin($username, $password, $loginUrl, $visitUrl, $userAgent, $cookieFile);
```

The $postData variable, has the username and password, of my wordpress.
I am getting this error from wordpress when I run it **ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.**

Even thought I've set a cookiejar for it, I get this, and I don't know why.

If I take out the testcookie=1 parameter from the $postData variable it's just showing me a blank page. I've tested the script yesterday, without the testcookie parameter and it worked, but I've reinstalled today my wordpress, and I get this cookie error.

So, in conclusion, if I leave the testcookie parameter, it's showing me an error. If I take it out, it's showing me a blank page.

And ideas ?

Comment: Depending on what you intend to do it might be easier to use the WordPress XMLRPC interface.

Comment: I have a bunch of stuff to do, but I am trying to use curl, because I want two functions that are not supported by xmlrpc (upload and activate a theme, and the same for a plugin).

Comment: @user3564958 Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile );`

Comment: @RahilWazir tried that, and now I get again a blank page.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution to this? I am using Jmeter for something like this ant it gives me same error :  Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.